# Cannot find Add Basemap option

Tags: arcgis-desktop, basemap, arcgis-10.7

I am new to GIS domain. Installed ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 on Windows 10. There is no "Add basemap" option even after proper internet connection.

What version of .NET framework do I need to have in my system for this?

Answer (score 2):

The first way is to click File -> data-> Add Data --> Add Basemap.

[image]

or, just find the Add Data Button 
[image]

If it will not work, then there is another way, by opening ArcCatalog. 
In Arcatalog, expand Add ArcGIS Server. 
[image]

Choose "Use GIS services"
[image]

In the Server URL put "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services" and click Finish.
[image]

below Gis Server, you will see "ArcGIS on server.arcgisonline.com (user)". Expand it and just drag and drop the service you want as basemap into ArcMap.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is located under the Add Data button as a pulldown of additional buttons to that one. It is revealed by clicking the small arrow at the bottom.

It may or may not be related but Esri have published [Problem: The Add Basemap option is missing in ArcMap](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014958) which refers to a .NET issue with similar symptoms at ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 and 10.4.1.

According to the [ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.x system requirements](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm):

> Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 or later must be installed prior to installing ArcMap.

so it may be worth checking whether that needs upgrading.

Comment: That arrow is not visible in this 10.7.1 version of ArcGIS. What other option is there?

Answer (score 0):

The arcGIS desktop 10.7.1 downloads/installs the arcScene setup instead of arcMaps. This is why there was no "Add Basemap" option.
I uninstalled this version (10.7.1) and installed ArcGIS desktop 10.6.1 that downloads/installs arcMaps correctly and the "Add basemap" option is also visible there.